# Div above content - moves down second following div

Tags: css-float

I am trying to add a div above my content div with the same width.
I would like it to only push down the content div, but it causes the sidebar div to move down as well.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="new-div">new div</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</div>
```

.

```
#container {
    background: lightgrey;
    width: 500px
}
#new-div {
    background: darkred;
    width: 300px
}
#content {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block
   }
#sidebar { 
    background: darkgreen;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zd9omqa7/2/

How can I avoid the sidebar div to move down? I would like it to always float in the right top corner.

Answer (score 0):

The two easiest ways that spring to mind would be to either reorder the html so your sidebar comes first in the DOM:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctaylr/xxhdn1xb/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div id="new-div">new div</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>

</div>
```

or to use position absolute to brute-force move it to the top:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctaylr/warnjgp3/2/

(remember to position the container div relative for this to work)

Otherwise, you could look to wrap your left hand side "divs" in a container of its own.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is that in some case the `#new-div` will actually happen to stretch 100% of the `#container` and IN THIS CASE should then push down the sidebar as well. But in the normal situation, if it is only the width of the content, it shouldn't.
The Problem with both the ways you suggested is that the `#sidebar` div will be steady in the top right corner also if the new-div happens to stretch 100% of the container.
For SEO reasons I am worried to put the sidebar first. In all my pages the sidebar goes after the content.

Comment: well adding a container (see: http://jsfiddle.net/ctaylr/zd9omqa7/3/) would allow you to do this without moving the HTML about, but it won't allow the layout to swap around if you are at 100% width. Will you know about this case in advance and be able to adjust the layout? Then you could use something like http://jsfiddle.net/ctaylr/zd9omqa7/6/ (uncomment the div above it for fullwidth)